How to skip Zero values when plotting a SwiftUI Chart
I am plotting a SwiftUI chart from a struct that looks like this:
struct BestWeights: Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    let date: String
    let maxWeight: Int
}

I am then creating an array of this struct that I will use to plot the chart:
 private var bestWeights: [BestWeights] {           
     let unformattedMonth = DateFormatter().monthSymbols[month - 1]
     let formattedMonth =  String(unformattedMonth.prefix(3))
     bestWeights.append(BestWeights(date: formattedMonth, maxWeight: bestWeightOfPeriod))
    
     //decrementing down one month
     selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: selectedDate) ?? selectedDate
}

Then I am iterating through bestWeights and plotting them:
Chart {
    ForEach(bestWeights) { bestWeight in
                        
        LineMark(x: .value("Date",bestWeight.date), y: .value("MaxWeight", bestWeight.maxWeight))
            .symbol {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
            }                        
    }
}

The Result:

This is not what I want. I don't want the 0's to be drawn on the Y axis. So I then added a check to not append any bestWeight where the weight is 0:
if(bestWeightOfPeriod != 0) {
    bestWeights.append(BestWeights(date: formattedMonth, maxWeight: bestWeightOfPeriod))
}

This is exactly what I want, but it creates another problem in my x-axis, where it's skipping months. It goes from Feb straight to June. I still want to mark all the months. Since the date is stored in my struct and it's skipping the months that have a 0 weight, it's not labeling the chart correctly.
How can I label those missing months?

I want the Y axis of the second image but the X axis of the first image.

It is the same y axis in both images isn’t it? I guess you want the values (dots) of the second image.

no the second one doesn't include any records that have a weight of 0 its why its x axis isn't proper like in image one, yes without those dots scrapping the bottom of the graph is what im looking for

So you want February to be just a single dot, and the line starts from June?

no I want February to Connect to June my only problem with the second image is that it is missing March April May on the X axis as a label

Filtering out the maxWeight == 0 data points is going in the right direction. You should keep doing that.
The problem is that you are using strings to represent months. Since you are plotting strings, the chart thinks they are a categorical data, instead of a time series.
First, change BestWeights into a Date:
struct BestWeights: Identifiable
{
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date // keep this a Date!
    let maxWeight: Int
}

Here is an example data set:
func weightsData() -> [BestWeights] {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var weights = [BestWeights]()
    for (month, weight) in zip(2...8, [90, 0, 0, 0, 100, 180, 100]) {
        let dateComponents = DateComponents(year: 2023, month: month, day: 1)
        let date = calendar.date(from: dateComponents)!
        weights.append(
            BestWeights(date: date, maxWeight: weight)
        )
    }
    return weights
}

and here is the chart:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var weights = weightsData().filter { $0.maxWeight > 0 }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(weights) { weight in
            LineMark(
                x: .value("Month", weight.date, unit: .month), // note the ".month" argument here!
                y: .value("Max Weights", weight.maxWeight)
            )
            .symbol {
                // Also consider using a PointMark here
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 7, height: 7)
            }
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            // here we add one axis mark per month
            AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) {
                // and here we format the date into an abbreviated month format
                AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated), centered: true)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Notice that I never explicitly turned a Date into a String. I just passed a format style to AxisValueLabel and it takes care of the formatting.
Output:


It's working better now but now in image two its going Feb, April, Jun. its still missing March, May and July

I have edited the answer to include your code

@johnsmith You should remove the first chartXAxis modifier, where you added AxisMarks(stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0)). You don't need that - there is no grid lines because I did not put AxisGridLine in the AxisMarks builder closure, where I put AxisValueLabel.

@johnsmith If you do want grid lines, you can add AxisGridLine(stroke: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1)) after AxisValueLabel.

Thank you for the excellent answer Im sure it will help many people the resources on Charts are quite limited

Just one last question if someone wanted instead of incrementing by month to increment by weeks i.e 10/7 , 17/7 , 24/7 etc.. How would they do it using your answer I can't find how to stride by week?

@johnsmith You can do .stride(by: .day, count: 7). Remember to also change the unit: parameter in x: .value("Month", weight.date, unit: .day).

And then what would you do to AxisValueLabel to make it show dd/MM on the X axis same as months?

@johnsmith .dateTime.month(.twoDigits).day() Please read the documentation.
